# Error when settingDBus property

Tags: python, qt5, dbus

I'm trying to set a property of a DBus Interface with Qt5.7.0.
This is the doc:

http://git.kernel.org/cgit/network/ofono/ofono.git/tree/doc/modem-api.txt

and I want to set the `Powered` property to `true`.
Here my code:

```
QDBusInterface *iface = new QDBusInterface("org.ofono", "/hfp/org/bluez/hci0/dev_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx", "org.ofono.Modem", QDBusConnection::systemBus());
iface->call("SetProperty", "Powered", QVariant(true));
```

and this is the error:

> QDBusError("org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod", "Method "SetProperty" with signature "sb" on interface "org.ofono.Modem" doesn't exist")

The path comes from the `GetModem` method and it's correct.
Also, I tried the same with Python:

```
modem = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object('org.ofono', '/hfp/org/bluez/hci0/dev_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx'), 'org.ofono.Modem')
modem.SetProperty('Powered', dbus.Boolean(1))
```

and it works fine! So the problem is definitely related to my Qt5 code.
How to better understand the error message? Is wrong my signature or it doesn't find the `SetProperty` method at all?

Comment: Well, it's true that "sb" isn't there, because it's "sv". Try just `true` without `QVariant` or try with `QDBusVariant`. And have you tried to generate classes from the XML definition?

Comment: The `call` method of `QDBusInterface` accepts only `QVariant` types. Using `true` alone leads to the very same message. I cannot find a reliable documentation about how to set/get DBus properties in Qt.

Comment: Perhaps I found the correct syntax after tons of trials: `iface->call("SetProperty", "Powered",  QVariant::fromValue(QDBusVariant(true)));`

Comment: In python with pyqt4, when using sip api 2 (where things are automatically converted), it seems there is no way to beg it to please use the `sv` signature over the `sb` one :-(